Garage ceiling is sagging / bowed
I have a finished ceiling in my garage, which has a second floor bedroom above. Everything is finished as you can see.
I noticed this was getting worse because the angle iron brackets shifted and the garage door was making a loud noise.
Does anyone know what might cause this? There are definitely no leaks from above and the rest of the garage ceiling is perfect.


it looks like it is coming down soon

Can you share any details about the structure?

Check the plans that were used, what size joists were used for the floor? Or was this a cheap / cowboy / cash job??

Certainly concerned since the angle bracket should be into the joist but can you cut a hole out of the plasterboard (its coming down anyway) just to check what is actually going on up there? I'd like to think it's just poorly secured plasterboard and the joists are fine...but maybe don't get your hopes up there.

Is the bedroom floor above sagging also?

Remove the stuff hanging from the ceiling and perhaps also the furniture and occupant above. Does NOT look good. Cheaper to get an engineer in and fix it before the bedroom is in the garage and the occupant is in the hospital.

"looks like it's coming down soon" - It's been like this for a while. Years probably, but seems to getting worse. I took a measurement when I fixed the garage door bracket so I can measure the change.

"share details about the structure": @AloysiusDefenestrate Unfortunately I'm not sure as the ceiling was finished when I moved in.

"bedroom floor sagging" @KenCarlson No sagging above.

@LioElbammalf I was thinking about cutting out a square to see what's going on before calling anyone.

Oddly, the white shelving rack behind has always been level and I put that up ~8 yeas ago.

@LioElbammalf I'm also not sure where to cut the hole to explore.

There's not enough information to help here. Do some exploration or find someone local who will. Just cut out some drywall, then cut out more if needed. You have an impending disaster to prevent. A dropped overhead door is serious business, and I don't want you raising my insurance premiums out of negligence.

I'd just start pulling down the drywall from the ceiling. Everywhere. You're going to want to get this fixed and it's going to have to come down anyway, may as well get a head start on it.

If the floor above is not sagging, then at least that part of the structure is good.  So it's something above the garage ceiling drywall and below the joist supporting the floor above.  Normally the garage ceiling drywall would be attached to the underside of the joists of the floor above. Are the garage door brackets and bike hanger just attached to the drywall alone?  Those things need to be attached to the ceiling joists, not just to the drywall.  You need to start cutting out sections of the drywall to see what's going on.

The bike rack 2x4 supports are secured using long lag bolts into the wooden joists. I used a detecter and then drilled pilot holes to ensure I was hitting wood. I haven't put a lot of weight on that (bike only).

From the picture, it appears that the ceiling where the bike rack is, is sagging.  But if the floor above is not sagging, then the bike rack can't possibly be attached to the underside of the upstairs floor joists.  So if it is attached to wood, that would have to mean that there is some other layer of wood inside that ceiling.  Once again, cutting holes and inspecting is necessary.
